# Flutter: Right overflowed by 18 pixels

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, flutter, dart

I'm Creating Login page inside my Flutter App. I've added those login content inside Row.

But when the app shows yellow bar saying

Right Overflowed by 18 pixels

I want to show only those contents which fits in 1st Row, All remaining content should get displayed below to it.

My snippet:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as an image

Answer (score 1):

Actually the code that you have posted is not complete, but from what I see is Row takes the max width so maybe you are getting the overflow, Maybe you should use a Expanded widget as a parent of the text Widgets so that it might work, It would be better if you post the full code, so that can tell you the where Exactly going wring.

Comment: Sure thing! 
Hope this helps, Would be great if you could rewrite the part which is faulty.
https://i.ibb.co/xHfJMS2/carbon-1.png

Answer (score 0):

the reason is some of your widget widths is higher than the phone screen width.
use listview((vertical)) inside Row to avoid that problem. you can scroll vertically that part